# Что означает T и U после модификаторов доступа, но до Function?

Tags: java

Что означает `T` и `U` после модификаторов доступа, но до `Function`?

```
static <T, U> Function<T, U> ternaryOperator
```

Comment: Я Java не знаю, но скорее всего это входной и выходной тип.

Comment: Строка кода у вас неполная, там должно быть что-то ещё. А означают они объявление типов-параметров дженерика ternaryOperator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это кусок определения [generic-метода](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html), т.е. метода, где конкретные классы, с которыми он работает, определяются в зависимости от классов переданных в него значений.

Допустим, есть какой-то метод, который принимает список значений и функцию, которая должна примениться к каждому значению, определение будет примерно такое:

```
public static <T, U> List<U> map(List<T> list, Function<T, U> function) {
    return list.stream().map(function).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

`<T, U>` тут просто обозначают, что в дальнейшем определении метода `T`, `U` это не названия каких-то классов, а шаблонные имена, вместо которых при вызове метода подставятся конкретные классы.

Ну и соответственно дальше эти "буквы" показывают, какие ограничения накладываются на принимаемые и возвращаемые значения.

Например, если первым параметром передать список целых (`List<Integer>`), то значит вторым параметром должна приниматься функция, принимающая целое число как параметр (вместо `T` будет конкретный класс `Integer`). Если передать функцию, которая принимает целое, а возвращает строку (`Function<Integer, String>`), значит возвращаться должен список строк (вместо `U` будет `String`).